# How do I post a form without the page refreshing in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, forms, post

I want to be able to post the following form without the page refreshing
in jquery and i need the form to post in information into actions.php

can somebody help me please?

```
<div id="postbox">
    <form method="post" id="ptowall">
        <input name="post" type="submit" value="Post" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#ptowall").bind("submit", function() { return false; });

$.post("your-form-submit-handler", $("#ptowall").serialize());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [$("form").serialize()](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serialize) command with the [Ajax functions](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax) for talking to the server.

Answer (score 0):

The [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) works really well and will do just what you're after.